# "most" or "the most" in the mentioned context?

Tags: word-choice, articles, definite-article

Should I use "most" or "the most" in the following context?

> Among all forms of intentionality the one that interest epistmologists
>   **most / the most** is X.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain which you think is correct, and why.  Also it would be good if you can include any research or examples that support your opinion, or explain why this is confusing?  Thanks.

Comment: The sentence in English would be phrased better this way: Of all the forms of intentionality, epistemologists are most interested in  x.

Comment: @Lambie That is a great answer. But then "most" does not mean "most of the epistemologists"?

Comment: @Lambie Also, in your suggested sentence, shouldn't we say "in all forms" instead of "in all the forms"?

Comment: @user157323 The forms of intentionality include A. B, C, D, E and F. Of all the forms of intionality, F is the most interesting. No, we should not say "in". Your original sentence does not say: most epistemologists. It is: to interest someone THE MOST, an adverb. Which can become: most interested in.

Answer (score 1):

**Among all forms of intentionality the one that interests epistemologists most / the most is X.**

Both forms are acceptable in everyday speech. The use of **the** before **most** is used to create a **superlative** form. In other words, the X form is at the top of the pile. It is THE MOST interesting to the epistemologists i.e. not the Z,Y or P forms, etc.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that here one would use: most interested in....I would think.

Comment: But isn't **most** superlative on it's own?

Comment: It seems nobody is sure about the answer, but 4 persons close-voted the question.